# Algorithm to reduce a Circuit-SAT to NAND-SAT

Tags: reductions, satisfiability, circuits, polynomial-time-reductions

I am trying to construct an algorithm to reduce OR, AND and NOT gates into NAND-SAT. Can someone give me a hint as to where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite each gate with its equivalent NAND construction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic